# babel copy files and build scss files

Tags: sass, babeljs

I'm running a babel cli command

`babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files`

To copy the es6 scripts from src into lib, and those files complied es5 scripts. And the sass files will be copyed to lib folder. But how can i build those sass files to css

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: so, you can't get my point?

Comment: Stackoverflow is full of people willing to help, but as many of those guides that I mentioned have very clear, it’s important to show your effort, once SO is not a “do for me” website. If you read the links and follow the guidelines, probably you will get your help more quickly.